# How to add a new blank line at the end of a JSON file?

Tags: json, r

I'm using rjson within R to read in a JSON file. It gives an error that StackOverflow indicated is due to it needing an (extra) blank line at the end of the JSON file. I'm not sure if JSON data normally has a blank line at the end, but the way I'm grabbing it currently there is not one.

Does anyone know how to insert one? Sorry to ask such a basic question. I found one answer online but I must be implementing it wrong or something. Here's how my code looks, where the second line is someone else's solution from another website that I'm apparently misusing:

```
json_file <- "C:\\Users\\bootydaddy\\Documents\\LookatHerBooty\\json.txt"
% echo "" >> json.txt
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Jason is asking about json! you must change your SO nickname:) The solution you give is nor reproducible. Does json.txt is the file where you get error?

Comment: LOL!  You're correct, the code I have doesn't work (that's why I need help). The file json.txt is just any json file that does not have a blank line at the end. It is not specific to any file (happens with all json files).  Here is where I saw the second line of code that does not work:  https://github.com/matsen/pplacer/issues/37

Comment: It's just a warning that you can suppress with `readLines(..., warn = FALSE)`

Comment: Can you not just add a newline via `fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), "\n" , collapse="")`?

Comment: I think that's the answer! thank you!

Comment: That sounds right actually, though I get still get the same error message. Maybe it's something like that but slightly different. I will keep trying, thanks.